A box contains many balls where $25$% are red. $1200$ balls are selected at random

A box contains many balls where $25$% are red. $1200$ balls are selected at random.


(a) What's the expected number of red balls pulled?

I think this problem can be represented by a Bernoulli Distribution so $E(X)=np=300$

(b) Probability that more than $315$ balls will be red?

I think this would be too big of a calculation if we add up each $P(X=316)+P(X=317)+...+P(X=1200)$ so am I allowed to assume random sampling from this distribution will follow a normal distribution (Central Limit Theorem)?:
We know that when selecting $1200$ balls that $E(X)=300$ and $Var(X)=np(1-p)=225$ so:
$$P\bigg(Z\gt \frac{315-300}{\sqrt{225}}\bigg)=1-\phi(1)=1-0.8413=0.1587$$. Is this correct?

This is poorly phrased.  As it stands, the total number matters.  Are we meant to assume a very large starting sample?

To be precise, if there were exactly $1200$ balls, then the selection would be the entire sample so would contain $300$ red balls.  But if the sample were bigger, the math would be different.

I believe you have the intended solution.  The fact that you are asked about an amount exactly one standard deviation high supports that.

A binomial distribution if you are assuming an infinite number of balls (or sampling with replacement).  A hypergeometric distribution if you are sampling without replacement from a known number of balls.

Your answer to part (a) is correct.
For part (b), you have the right idea, but for best results, you will want to employ continuity correction.  If $X$ is the random number of balls in the sample that are red, then
$$X \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n = 1200, p = 0.25)$$
and we are specifically asked for
$$\Pr[X > 315].$$  We then approximate the distribution of $X$ with a normal distribution with the same mean and variance as $X$; i.e.,
$$X \approx \operatorname{Normal}(\mu = np = 300, \sigma^2 = np(1-p) = 225)$$
which would give
$$\Pr[X > 315] = \Pr\left[\frac{X - \mu}{\sigma} > \frac{315 - 300}{\sqrt{225}}\right] \approx \Pr[Z > 1] \approx 0.1586552539.$$
as you had calculated, but there is a subtlety here.  $X$ is discrete, but $Z \sim \operatorname{Normal}(0,1)$ is continuous, so in order to exclude half of the binomial probability mass occurring at $Z = 1$, we must instead write
$$\Pr[X > 315] \approx \Pr\left[Z > \frac{315.5 - 300}{\sqrt{225}}\right] = \Pr[Z > \tfrac{31}{30}] \approx 0.150723966569.$$
The exact binomial probability can be evaluated using a computer:
$$\begin{align}
\Pr[X > 315] &= 1 - \Pr[X \le 315] \\
&= 1 - \sum_{x=0}^{315} \binom{1200}{x} (0.25)^x (0.75)^{1200-x} \\
&= 0.15079843513649\ldots. \end{align}$$
Notice how the continuity-corrected normal approximation is more accurate.
